# Compress-Archive Error: Cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: powershell

I would like to zip a path (with a service windows running inside).

When the service is stopped, it works perfectly, when the service is running, I have the exception:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process.

However, when I zip with 7-zip, I don't have any exception.

My command:

```
Compress-Archive [PATH] -CompressionLevel Optimal -DestinationPath("[DEST_PATH]") -Force
```

Do you have any idea to perform the task without this exception?

Comment: try to use 7zip from powershell for workaround, see https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-and-7Zip-83020e74

Comment: _Do you have any idea to perform the task without this exception ?_ Using Snapshots?

Comment: The error is on a file (.dll) that is not modified. So a snapshot should not be a problem

Comment: @Manu I approved your edit. When editing, please also [remove things like "Thanks"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/168333). Keep up the good work!

Comment: @Bob: I meant you should use snapshots to avoid your exception. See my answer.

Comment: @Bob: Did my answer help you in any way?

Answer (score 7):

`Copy-Item` allows you to access files that are being used in another process.

This is the solution I ended up using in my code:

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Temp\somefolder" -Force -PassThru | 
Get-ChildItem |
Compress-Archive -DestinationPath "C:\Temp\somefolder.zip"
```

The idea is that you pass through all the copied items through the pipeline instead of having to copy them to a specific destination first before compressing.

I like to zip up a folder's content rather than the folder itself, therefore I'm using `Get-ChildItem` before compressing in the last line.

Sub-folders are already included. No need to use `-recurse` in the first line to do this

Comment: Note, this overwrites (if you run this multiple times, for example) and then leaves the copied file in the current working directory.

Comment: I was just playing with this method and it looks like when you do `Copy-Item`, even though you're piping it, it copies the files to your PWD. So for me, it happened to be C:\Windows\System32...it was creating a bunch of junk in there.

Comment: This as the big disadvantage to copy the files to your PWD as other said. Unwanted side effect

Answer (score 2):

A good method to access files being used by another process is by creating snapshots using [Volume Shadow Copy Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384649(v=vs.85).aspx).

To do so, one can simply use PowerShells WMI Cmdlets:

```
$Path = "C:/my/used/folder"
$directoryRoot = [System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectoryRoot($Path).ToString()

$shadow = (Get-WmiObject -List Win32_ShadowCopy).Create($directoryRoot, "ClientAccessible")
$shadowCopy = Get-WmiObject Win32_ShadowCopy | ? { $_.ID -eq $shadow.ShadowID }
$snapshotPath = $shadowCopy.DeviceObject + "\" + $Path.Replace($directoryRoot, "")
```

Now you can use the `$snapshotPath` as `-Path` for your `Compress-Archive` call.

This method can also be used to create backups with symlinks. 
From there on you can use the linked folders to copy backed up files, or to compress them without those Access exceptions.

I created a similiar function and a small Cmdlet in this Gist: [Backup.ps1](https://gist.github.com/Clijsters/ee681d0faa4a078244514f7dae92dda7)

Answer (score 2):

There was a similar requirement where only few extensions needs to be added to zip.
With this approach, we can copy the all files including locked ones to a temp location > Zip the files and then delete the logs

This is bit lengthy process but made my day!

```
$filedate = Get-Date -Format yyyyMddhhmmss
$zipfile = 'C:\Logs\logfiles'+ $filedate +'.zip'

New-Item -Path "c:\" -Name "Logs" -ItemType "directory" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Robocopy "<Log Location>" "C:\CRLogs\" *.txt *.csv *.log /s
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Logs\" -Recurse | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $zipfile -Force -ErrorAction Continue
Remove-Item -Path "C:\Logs\" -Exclude *.zip -Recurse -Force
```