# PowerShell: Creating an archive of a folder and subfolders when some files are used by another process

Tags: powershell, compress-archive

I need to create an archive of a folder with certain subfolders (having some folders/files excluded) in PowerShell using compress-archive command.

For example, here is a folder structure:

```
c:\Temp\Folder
log1.log
log1_1.txt

c:\Temp\Folder\Folder1\
log2.log
log2_1.log

c:\Temp\Folder\Folder2\
log3.log
log3_1.log
```

Need to exclude Folder2.
As a result, the following folders / files have to be included to the zip file:

```
c:\Temp\Folder
log1.log
log1_1.txt

c:\Temp\Folder\Folder1\
log2.log
log2_1.log
```

Since some files are being used by another process, had to follow the recommendation below:

[Compress-Archive Error: Cannot access the file because it is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47262348/compress-archive-error-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-anoth)

Here is a script:

```
Copy-Item -Path "c:\temp\folder\*" -Exclude "Folder2" -Force -PassThru | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath c:\temp1\archive.zip
```

However, only "c:\Temp\Folder" folder files are being included in the archive:

```
log1.log
log1_1.txt
```

Using -recurse (in Copy-Item) does include the files from Folder1, but does not keep Folder1 in the archive. So I am getting all the files from the subfolder inside archive.zip, which is not what I need.

I need the below structure of archive.zip:

```
log1.log
log1_1.txt
Folder1\
log2.log
log2_1.log
```

I tried using get-Item / get-child-Item and pipe it to copy-item - no luck - getting all files from the subfolders without folders name.

I figured out out that if I run the command below:

```
Copy-Item -Path "c:\temp\folder\folder1" -Force -PassThru -Recurse | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath c:\temp1\archive.zip
```

It creates and archive file with the below files/folders:

```
log2.log
log2_1.log
Folder1\
log2.log
log2_1.log
```

So after I deleted archive.zip and ran initial command - it is working as expected even after client reboot.

```
Copy-Item -Path "c:\temp\folder\*" -Exclude "Folder2" -Force -PassThru | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath c:\temp1\archive.zip
```

The content of zip file:

```
log1.log
log1_1.txt
Folder1\
log2.log
log2_1.log
```

I've tried it on different windows clients: win2012/2016/2019 same behavior.

If I rename c:\Temp\Folder\Folder1\ to c:\Temp\Folder\Folder3\ it stops including Folder3 folder and its contents to zip file unless I follow the above steps to get it "fixed".

Not sure why this is happening.

How to get it working properly?
Appreciate your time!

Thank you!

Comment: Try using XCOPY instead of Copy-ITEM.  XCOPY is a cmd.exe method that will also work in a powershell script.  I've had cases where Copy-Item didn't work and XCOPY did work.

Comment: Thanks! IMHO, this method requires an additional space on the disk, which is not what I am looking for, unless there is a way to pipe scopy to compress-archive using -passthru flag - same way we are doing with 'copy-item'.

Comment: XCopy goes to standard output so you can pipe it to a PS cmdlet just like any other pipes in PS.

Comment: Thanks! Trying to use the below syntax, but it is not working: xcopy 'c:\temp\folder'  | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath c:\temp1\zip_1.zip     hung on 'the archive file <name> creation in progress...'

Comment: Why do you need XCOPY? Compress-Archive will compress a folder.

Comment: There is a problem to archive an open file : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47262348/compress-archive-error-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-anoth

Comment: Did some searching an lots of people had similar issues.  XCOPY to an archive nobody got working.

Comment: the workaround provided in the thread I referenced is using copy-item to copy opened files. However, this method does not process sub-folders. To process sub-folders need to use -recurse, but in this case it does not keep a folder structure. I noticed an "odd behavior" when it started working as expected after for the subfolders, but this cannot be used on a random machine.

Comment: I know.  That is why I recommended xcopy.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this script to achieve your requirement

```
$sourceFolder = "C:\Temp\Folder"

$destinationArchive = "C:\temp1\Archive.zip"

$excludeFolders = @("Folder3", "Folder5")

$tempFolder = "C:\Users\Downloads\TempFolder"

New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $tempFolder

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Exclude $excludeFolders | Copy-Item -Destination $tempFolder -Recurse

Compress-Archive -Path $tempFolder -DestinationPath $destinationArchive

Remove-Item -Path $tempFolder -Force -Recurse
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! Using tempfolder requires an additional space on the disk. Unfortunately, it is not what I am looking for.

Comment: So you want to add a selected folder in the archive directly without creating an additional folder. Is this the requirement?

Comment: I want to add a folder with files and its subfolder with files,  having the name of the subfolder included in archive. Using copy-item without -recurse omitting the subfolder, whiles using -recurse includes all the files from subfolder, but not including the name of the subfolder to archive.  Thanks -

Answer (score 0):

i hope this script will help you. This will archive the folder with subfolder and files as well

```
$sourceFolder = "C:\Temp\Folder"
$destinationArchive = "C:\temp1\Archive.zip"
$includeFolders = @("folder2", "folder5")
Compress-Archive -Path (Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Directory | Where-Object { $_.Name -in $includeFolders }).FullName -DestinationPath $destinationArchive
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, it works for the files that are not opened by application, which is running on this client. If there is a file that is being used by app, I am getting the below error:

Comment: ZipArchiveHelper : The process cannot access the file 'C:\Temp\Folder\Folder2\process.log' because it is being used by another process.
The workaround is to use a temp folder and use copy-item command to backup this file or files.
Also, the problem is that compress-archive exits immediately due to this error and does not create any archive.zip
I tried to add "-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue" or even "Ignore" to compress-archive command, but this did not help.

Comment: In my case the workaround is to manually exclude the file from the backup list and backup all the files then use copy-item method for that file only, just to "update" the archive.
However, there is a chance that it could be a random temp file/name next time, which will not be excluded.
Question: How to make the "compress-archive" to proceed and backup rest of the files in case of "The process cannot access the file '<file_name>' because it is being used by another process."?
Tried to use try/catch method, but this did not help. Maybe I am using incorrect syntax?
Appreciate your time!

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Hi Norman, you are getting the message that the file is being used by another process. We can copy, move, or delete the file while some process is using the file. what we can do is, we can use conditions to skip the file or stop the process before archiving the file.

Comment: thx.. yes, the compress-archive cannot add the file used by another process to archive. If the file name is unknown, what would be the condition in this case? Also, can we "tell" compress-archive to continue in case of an error? As compress-archive just stop processing all other files in the list and deletes zip file. Thank you!